# Remove Text from XML File using Bash

Tags: xml, bash, shell, sed, xml-namespaces

I have a bash script that generates an xml file (drivers_list.xml) and has to subsequently remove this line:

```
xmlns="http://feed.elasticstats.com/schema/nascar/series-v2.0.xsd"
```

By looking around this page I found some suggestions and attempted,

```
sed -i '' "s/xmlns=\"http://feed.elasticstats.com/schema/nascar/series-v2.0.xsd\"//g" drivers_list.xml
```

Unfortunately, when I run it, I get the following error:

```
sed: 1: "s/xmlns="http://feed.el ...": bad flag in substitute command: 'f'
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: some thing wrong with the pattern split character in the search string or replace string. in your case, you could use `#` instead of `/` as pattern split character, so it didn't need to escape the `/` in search or replace string, like `sed "s#original_string_without_she#new_string_without_she#/g" drivers_list.xml`.

Comment: welcome to SO, one more thing as the same, you could use single quote `'` instead of  double quote `"` to contain the `s/regexp/replacement/`, so you didn't need to escape the `"` in the pattern string, because your pattern string didn't contain the `'` in this case. I can't find the pattern split character with English link, I only found a Chinese link(http://blog.chinaunix.net/uid-12072359-id-2960859.html), maybe you could understand it by translator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to escape all slashes(`/`) and use two types of quotes(`'`,`"`):

```
sed -i 's/xmlns=\"http:\/\/feed.elasticstats.com\/schema\/nascar\/series-v2.0.xsd\"//g' drivers_list.xml
```

Then the output should be as expected.
Of course, with this approach you will not catch the `xmlns='...'` definitions - which are equally valid.

Comment: `You have to escape all slashes(/) ` it make no sense, you could use other pattern split character such as `# / ,`, so it didn't need to escape the character which not equal the pattern split character.

Answer (score 0):

Find it -- [Delimiters in sed substitution](https://coderwall.com/p/khdkuw/delimiters-in-sed-substitution)

```
Sed can use any character as a delimiter. 
In fact, it will automatically use the character following the `s` as a delimiter.
```